# Pass PHP variable to Javascript and then save it to a text file

Tags: javascript, php, save

I am using this script to save a PHP variable (here $CODE, which is a text I get from a sql request) to a file.

```
  function download_txt() {
  var textToSave = <?= json_encode($CODE) ?>; 
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', download_txt);
```

But it does not work. The file remains empty.
I guess it has to do with the json encoding but I am kind of lost.

Comment: maybe your text got special character that need to be escped

Comment: found the problem: I cannot decode #

Answer (score 0):

Seems working for me

```
<?php
    $CODE = array('j', 'k');

?>
<button id="test">Download</button>
<script>
function download_txt() {
  var textToSave = <?= json_encode($CODE) ?>;
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
}
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', download_txt);
</script>
```

Comment: # XX XX R-Blog
myX<-1:10 
myY<-jitter(1:10) # add some noise
adjust<-lm(myX ~ myY)
plot(myX,myY,abline(adjust))
summary(adjust)[4]
summary(adjust)[8]

Comment: The text above is the variable. There are indeed lots of special characters